# Wordpress server change - slow admin login time for first time

Tags: wp-admin, wp-login-form, wp-load.php

I have a large Wordpress site.

On local system we create a git repo for deploy a local version of Wordpress to DigitalOcean VPS servers. All Works great, but here is a problem to update a sql database.

I use this script to change pachs from `localhost/project` to `servers ip`.

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

All works good, but after open on **first time** `ip/wp-login.php` or `wp-admin` take a login, server is going loading admin page about 3-5 mins, sometimes server goes down. This is only on first time after full database update.

I also use this Wordpress SQL migrate plugin:

https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db

At there is the same, **first time after synchronization of wordpress mysql**, wordpress admin page on only first time load slow.

On server we use DigitalOcean with LAMP configuration (Ubuntu)